# Enumerate within a list

Tags: lists, enumerate

Suppose I want to use enumerate within a `\list`. In my example, the first enumerate (before `some text`) works properly, but the second enumerate (after `some text`) does not. I would like to know why.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcounter{questioncounter}
\newenvironment{question}{% 
    \refstepcounter{questioncounter}
    \list{\thequestioncounter .}{%
        \item
}}{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item enumerate 1, item 1 (OK)
\item enumerate 1, item 2 (OK)
\end{enumerate}

some text (OK)

\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item enumerate 2, item 1 (NOT OK)
\item enumerate 2, item 2 (NOT OK)
\end{enumerate}

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate`, at least in its standard version from `latex.ltx` uses an `\list` internally too. The outer `\list` from the `question` environment` and the inner ones interfere, it's better to group them, to protect the list depth/enum depth counters.

I don't understand why an outer `\list` is used at all.

I've provided two ways -- with `enumitem` and its `shortlabels` option and the more sophisticated `label=...` approach.

Using `enumitem` with the `indent/leftmargin` features would provide a `\list` -less way, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\newcounter{questioncounter}

\newenvironment{question}{% 
  \refstepcounter{questioncounter}
 \list{\thequestioncounter .}{%
 \item
   \begingroup
 }%
 \endgroup
}{\endlist}


\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item enumerate 1, item 1 (OK)
  \item enumerate 1, item 2 (OK)
  \end{enumerate}
  % Some text (OK)
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item enumerate 2, item 1 (Now OK)
  \item enumerate 2, item 2 (Now OK)
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

With more sophisticated \verb!enumitem! - features

\begin{question}
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
  \item enumerate 1, item 1 (OK)
  \item enumerate 1, item 2 (OK)
  \end{enumerate}
  % Some text (OK)
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
  \item enumerate 2, item 1 (Now OK)
  \item enumerate 2, item 2 (Now OK)
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ``\begingroup`` and ``\endgroup`` tags in the ``question`` environment solved my question. As for why I used a ``\list`` - suppose I number the question 1 - 11. I wanted to use the questioncounter for these questions and be able to right align these question numbers. I'm not aware that this is possible using ``enumerate``

Comment: @nathanesau: Please have a look into `enumitem` and it's alignment etc. features.